# How to remove the legend from MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, linechart

[image: Check image]

How to remove origin small square? I am using [Philjay library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Comment: Are you sure that's an origin? Looks like a data-point to me, as it is not on the zero of the vertical axis. How many data points have you tried to render? Can you check that in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the `Legend`. You did not provide a label for your `DataSet` so it only shows the form and no text.

You can disable it via this line of code

```
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer